# Video does not play, only plays audio, when using Google Drive API for large files

Tags: html

```
<video controls="" controlslist="nodownload"> <source src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1WTZUmV4mu0PHCZMElHbfiBAJecsL207r?alt=media&key=AIzaSyB-GdbjCJN1ehSJq50J7smNuPakwohsa" type="video/mp4"></source> </video>
```

My video is over 100mb so I used the Google Drive API. But when attached to the video tag, it doesn't play the video, only the audio

[image]

Comment: Does the same file play correctly if loaded from your local machine?

Comment: I tried to put the src in the local path, but I see the same thing (sound but no picture). However, the video is still viewed normally on the video player. There is no way to fix it?

Comment: With video preview on google drive still running normally
Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WTZUmV4mu0PHCZMElHbfiBAJecsL207r/view?usp=sharing